# How to tell my advisor that I would probably search for a job?

Tags: phd, advisor, salary

A bit of background: I'm a non-european phd student in europe doing a phd in a computational field. Recently I've applied and obtained a grant. The grant came with a unfortunate pay cut of 15% and I was barely scraping by with my pre-grant salary (paid from my advisor's project). I've accepted the grant as it was more secure (I was assured funding for a certain amount of years). I've asked my advisor if I could teach for the difference in my salary, which I was declined due to language restrictions. I was offered an alternative to that, a software developer position. But my advisor keeps postponing the signing of the contract for that stating issues like accounting trouble at university administration. Its been six months I've been on this reduced salary, to a point that I have to borrow to survive. I've applied for a two jobs and got interviewed for one. The results are still unknown. I'm not sure if it will impact our professional relationship if I mention to him that I'm going to search of a second job. How would i approach this?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to approach this is directly, saying to them that you are unable to live at the level of funding you are currently getting and need to supplement it somehow. Say that a job is one possibility if they can't provide any additional funding relatively soon, but you need a resolution. Say you are flexible, but the current situation is untenable.

If they say there is no resolution possible then you have to make hard decisions about leaving for something better. It might delay your career a bit but the long term might be better. Hard decisions.

If you have family obligations, as many do, it can be an additional incentive both for you and your advisor to find a solution.